# Why "readFile" method places file's content into the memory in contrast with "readFileSync"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, garbage-collection

Here is an example of NodeJS code (synchronous version):

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = './parseLogFiles/reports';
var counter = 0;
var totalFileSize = 0;
var fileName;
var fullPath;

function toMb (byteVal) {
    return (byteVal / 1048576).toFixed(2);
}

var filesList = fs.readdirSync(path);

console.log('Memory usage before files read:', toMb(process.memoryUsage()['heapUsed']) + ' MB');

for (var i = 0, len = filesList.length; i < len; i++) {

    fileName = filesList[i];

    if (fileName) {

        fullPath = path + '/' + fileName;

        totalFileSize += fs.statSync(fullPath)['size'];

        try {
            fs.readFileSync(fullPath, {encoding: 'utf8'});
        } catch(err){
            console.log('err: ', err);
        }

    }

}

console.log('Memory usage after files read:', toMb(process.memoryUsage()['heapUsed']) + ' MB');
console.log('Total files size:', toMb(totalFileSize) + ' MB');
```

I have got the following results:

Memory usage before files read: 22.45 MB
Memory usage after files read: 23.31 MB
Total files size: 258.19 MB

Here is asynchronous version:

```
...

for (var i = 0, len = filesList.length; i < len; i++) {

    fileName = filesList[i];

    if (fileName) {

        fullPath = path + '/' + fileName;

        (function(fullPath){
            fs.stat(fullPath, function(err, stat){
                totalFileSize += stat['size'];
                fs.readFile(fullPath, {encoding: 'utf8'}, function(){
                    if (++counter === len) {
                        console.log('Memory usage after files read:', toMb(process.memoryUsage()['heapUsed']) + ' MB');
                        console.log('Total files size:', toMb(totalFileSize) + ' MB');
                    }
                });
            });
        })(fullPath);

    }

}
```

I have got the following results:

Memory usage before files read: 22.45 MB
Memory usage after files read: 437.88 MB
Total files size: 258.19 MB

Why does it happen (23.31 MB vs 437.88 MB)?

Answer (score 2):

In your synchronous version, the data gets garbage collected, because you don't assign the return value to anything.  In the asynchronous one, the final file isn't allowed to be garbage collected because it's accessible via `arguments`, even though you haven't set an explicit parameter.

To prove this, I set up a simple test on a single file.  I got results similar to yours in the basic version (although I had to force gc before each memory usage check).  However, if I just store the data from the return of `readFileSync`, that version uses almost exactly the same amount of memory as the async one.

If you're worried about memory usage, you should be using [fs.createReadStream](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options).

Comment: thanks for your reply. It was very informative. Can i make the conclusion that the reason in the design of JavaScript language, but not in NodeJs realization of "readFileSync" and "readFile" methods?

Comment: @Carl It's a mix of the two, I think.  For example, `readFileSync` _could_, in theory, return data by synchronously calling a callback, and then it would have the same memory usage as the async version.  On the other hand, the fact that `arguments` exists is also kinda to blame.  Why do you feel the need to blame one or the other?  The context of the question is probably important.

Comment: Aaron. I do not feel the need to blame. I want to understand :)